# setState() of an object within an object with a variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to `setState()` an object that is within an object but with a variable as a key.

```
const [student, setStudent] = useState({
   Bob: {id: 1, food: "carrot"},
    
   Dave: {id: 2, food: "potato"},
    
   Emily: {id: 3, food: "apple"}
});
```

variable `randomStudent` can be Bob, Dave, or Emily

```
setStudent(prev => ({...prev, [randomStudent].food : "steak"}))\
```

The code above doesn't seem to work, how can I fix this?

Comment: how abt this `[randomStudent]['food'] = "steak"` ?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is invalid syntax. You can't update a single property like you're trying to do. Instead do something like the following:

```
setStudent(prev => ({
  ...prev,
  [randomStudent]: {
    ...prev[randomStudent], // spread (shallow copy) the original
    food : "steak"          // update the property you want
  }
}));
```

---

This is obviously a lot more verbose but still necessary. If you want a better experience you can try [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide object in value when using spread operator

```
setStudent(prev => ({...prev, [randomStudent]: {id: 1, food : "steak"} }))
```

Or

```
setStudent(prev => {
  prev[randomStudent].food = 'steak';
  return {...prev}
})
```